# Ranking in Spotfire with Multiple arguments

Tags: spotfire, ranking, tie

New to spotfire here and have a question:
I need to rank people based on a few different criteria. 
"Start_date" is the most important. If there is a tie for "start_date" I want to rank by "Age" and if there is still a tie because they started the same day and are the same age I want to then look at badge number as the final tie breaker.

All the RANK() function in spotfire produce a numeric ranking and tie breakers dont seem to be based on anything beyond min, max average.

Any help would be apprecaited!!

Answer (score 0):

I mocked up some data:

[image]

I then created the following column:

```
rank(Concatenate([Start Date],[Age],[Bnumber]),"asc") as [Rank]
```

[image]

If I understand corectly, this should solve your needs. The first person has been there the longest, and wins the tie break based on age and then badge number. Whether age/badge number being the lowest or highest you did not specify. It then iterates until the last person has been there the shortest.